# How can I use the Twitter API to get tweets for a specific user and timeframe?

Tags: api, web-applications, twitter

I've been doing some research into using the Twitter API, and I'm not sure if I'm understanding it correctly. I want to get tweets from a specific user for a specific time-frame. From what I can tell, using the search function to specify a date range doesn't work because only the last 7 days are kept. I could just get the tweets and work out the date range with JavaScript, but the documentation states the the max you can get is 200 tweets, so if the tweets from the date range I want aren't in the last 200 I can't do it.

Is there anyway I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the page=n URL argument to go back through the previous pages of 200 status updates.

as described here:

http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline